# Flutter await Future function not working as expected

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to check if a record exists before performing the return Streambuilder part of my code. The check sets a boolean which should tell the Streambuilder which Firebase Firestore query to run. The check is in an async function which awaits the checking code. However I see from the prints that the check is always being executed after the Streambuilder return.
Here is the code:

```
Future<void> checkIfReceiver(String sndId, String rxId) async {
isReceiver = await chats.chatExistsForUserCombination(
    senderId: sndId, receiverId: rxId);
}

@override
build(BuildContext context) {

checkIfReceiver(member.id, currentUserId);

return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: isReceiver
      ? _firestore
          .collection('messages')
          .where("senderId", isEqualTo: member.id)
          .where("receiverId", isEqualTo: currentUserId)
          .orderBy("timeStamp")
          .snapshots()
      : _firestore
          .collection('messages')
          .where("senderId", isEqualTo: currentUserId)
          .where("receiverId", isEqualTo: member.id)
          .orderBy("timeStamp")
          .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      print("NO DATA IN SNAPSHOT");
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        ),
      );
    }
```

and:

```
Future<bool> chatExistsForUserCombination(
  {required String senderId, required String receiverId}) async {
final extracted = await _firestore
    .collection('messages')
    .where("senderId", isEqualTo: senderId)
    .where("receiverId", isEqualTo: receiverId)
    .orderBy("timeStamp")
    .get();

if (extracted.docs.isNotEmpty) {
  print("TRUE..");
  return true;
} else {
  print("FALSE..");
  return false;
}
```

}

please note the returned value from "chatExistsForUserCombination", is correct.

The problem i see is that the print true or false from that method is always after the "NO DATA IN SNAPSHOT" print in the main body of the builder.

Any help with understanding this would be really appreciated. It was my understanding that the await tells the program to wait until that piece of code has finished before progressing. So getting quote confused with it.

Many thanks

Comment: `checkIfReveiver` is also `async`, but you're not `await`ing it. What happens if you `await` it?

Comment: Simply put, you cannot call anything that returns a future from `build`. `build` *must* complete and return immediately (and it's not async so you cannot await anything.) You are close, though. You have this boolean `isReceiver` that you can use safely in `build`. What you need to do is to `setState` whenever that changes, so that `build` gets called again and can pick up the new value and return the correct widgets based on the new, current value. It there isn't a good default for `isReceiver` while you wait to find out its real value, consider making `isReceiver` a `bool?`...

Comment: ... this way it can be null and your `build` can decide to return a progress indicator while it's null, then whichever stream builder once you know its value.